# Google drive api and service account

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I created service account for my account name@steelkiwi.com(Google apps) and my application works fine. Then I created service account for my personal account name@gmail.com, use this new credentials for my application and now when I try to insert files I get error 500 with next text:

> HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?quotaUser=30&uploadType=resumable&convert=true&ocr=false&alt=json returned "Internal Error"

The only thing that changes is credentials SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL and SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH. I have tried to create another service account for name@steelkiwi.com but it doesn't help, so bacically my app only works with first service account.
Language is python.

Comment: Are you using Google APIs python client library?

Comment: In normal circumstances, all you need to change is the email and the private key and 500 is not expected due to wrong credentials.

Comment: Yes, I'm use google-api-python-client. And I have exponential backoff but it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Which user are you trying to impersonate? Impersonation is not available for gmail accounts, but only for Google Apps domain admins.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your answer. Both account are mine.

Comment: Both accounts are yours but, while using a service account, you don't authenticate for yourself. You authenticate on the behalf of a service that may perform operations on the behalf of a user (called impersonation). It's different than going through the OAuth2 flow where you explicitly ask permissions from a user. That's why we only give impersonalization permissions to domain admins for the users on their own domain, otherwise it'll be a security issue. It's a little bit complicated to understand the difference when a service account belongs to the person you want to impersonate.

Comment: tl;dr: Only an Apps admin account can impersonate a user only if the user is in his domain. For other cases, you need to go through a Web server or installed app based OAuth 2.0 flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure what happened maybe something was fixed after this accident http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&ts=1366405199000&iid=369723584758ad9cdfd010ac44c8272e
but now all works fine. At first I created simple small app from examples that work with service accounts https://gist.github.com/mobedigg/5420958 I have used my credentials for this app and it's works so I put this credentials to my main code and it's worked too. Nothing was changed in main code except credentials. Also I tried other credentials on this small app and they are worked with it and worked with main code. It's very odd.

Comment: found useful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479564/not-able-to-access-google-drive-files-with-service-account

Answer (score 0):

If you create a service account with your apps domain admin, you should be able to impersonate all users by changing the `prn` attribute below. If you don't set a `prn` user that is out of your domain, you should see an access error.

```
f = open('path-to-privatekey.p12')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', prn='user@steelkiwi.com')

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials.authorize(http)

client = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

Comment: Looks like we on wrong way. I don't need to impersonate other accounts. I need to change accounts. I have SERVICE_ACCOUNT_1 created for (name@steelkiwi.com), I want to use SERVICE_ACCOUNT_2 created for(name@gmail.com) in api console of name@gmail.com. Here is code [https://gist.github.com/mobedigg/5397051](https://gist.github.com/mobedigg/5397051) I marked with inline comment string where I have error.

Comment: Your code LGTM and works for me. Is there anything you've changed -- like the file you're uploading? 500 is unlikely to be caused by auth.

Comment: No. I change only SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL and SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH all other things are the same.