# Google Vision raises a Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to run the quick start demo by [Google Vision APIs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/quickstart.py) on MacOS Sierra.

```
def run_quickstart():
    # [START vision_quickstart]
    import io
    import os

    # Imports the Google Cloud client library
    from google.cloud import vision

    # Instantiates a client
    vision_client = vision.Client()

    # The name of the image file to annotate
    file_name = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'resources/wakeupcat.jpg')

    # Loads the image into memory
    with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
        image = vision_client.image(
            content=content)

    # Performs label detection on the image file
    labels = image.detect_labels()

    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label.description)
    # [END vision_quickstart]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Script looks as above. I am using Service Account key file to authenticate. As document suggested I have installed google-vision dependencies via pip and set up an environment variable with,

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/my_credentials.json
```

Environment variable is correctly set. Still script raises,

> oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.

There are similar questions asked when using API keys, when using Service account file was not mentioned.

Comment: you might want to try and find a Python service account example for another API and get that working first. There are two different service account key files now P12 and json.   You need to be sure the code you are using is for the file that you are using.   My python knowlage is limited so I cant be much more help.    http://stackoverflow.com/a/16039748/1841839  looks to me like you are using the wring file

Comment: @DaImTo appreciate your help! Will try it out!